# Support for Content-Encoding and Content-Decoding with Vert.x WebClient

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus, mutiny

```
public VertxHttpClient(Vertx vertx) {
    this(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setTryUseCompression(true));
}
```

when I add accept-encoding header to the request.

```
kernelHttpRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

The Vert.x-WebClient/3.9.5 ignores this header and The response which i receive from server does not have "content-encoding" header option.

Rather it have header as  "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked".

```
"headers": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": [
            "chunked"
        ],
```

How can i pass accept-encoding = gzip and decompress the response which i am getting from server with Vert.x-WebClient/3.9.5

Comment: Are you sure the client is not setting this header? Have you verified with a network capture tool? Maybe it's the server that is ignoring it

Comment: If I remove setTryUseCompression(true) and add explicit accept-encoding header as gzip, I get the response header as content-encoding. But then web client is not able to decompress the response by default.

Answer (score 0):

you should create the client with the appropriate option independantly of chunking:

```java
client = vertx.createHttpClient(createBaseClientOptions().setTryUseCompression(true));
```

The `setTryUseCompression` actually tell the client to set an `accept-encoding` header to `gzip` and will decompress the response when the server has set the `content-encoding` header to `gzip`.

This is explained in the documentation https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_enabling_compression_on_the_client

Comment: ```public VertxHttpClient(Vertx vertx) {
    this(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setTryUseCompression(true));
} ```


is same as of


```client = vertx.createHttpClient(createBaseClientOptions().setTryUseCompression(true));
```

I dont see any difference

Comment: Also we are using WebClient instead of HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `setTryUseCompression= true` while creating your Webclient which tells client to set an accept-encoding header to gzip and will decompress under the hood the response when the server has set the content-encoding header to gzip.
2. For my use I could not afford to set `setTryUseCompression` on my whole WebClient as it was being used in a complicated application, which in turn was making my other calls to fail.
   So I had to write a custom decoder to decompress the response . Here is what I did. May be it will be helpful for someone in the future.

```
  private String decompressErrorBody(HttpResponse<Buffer> response) throws IOException {
    if ("gzip".equals(response.getHeader("Content-Encoding"))) {
      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body().getBytes());
      GZIPInputStream zipped = new GZIPInputStream(is);
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipped));
      StringWriter responseBody = new StringWriter();
      PrintWriter responseWriter = new PrintWriter(responseBody);
      String line = null;
      while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        responseWriter.println(line);
      }
      return responseBody.toString();
    } else {
      return response.bodyAsString();
    }
  }
```